# Using Elasticsearch to search special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I force Elasticsearch query_string to recognize '@' as a simple character?

Assuming I have an Index, and I added a few documents, by this statement:

```
POST test/item/_bulk
{"text": "john.doe@gmail.com"} 
{"text": "john.doe@outlook.com"}
{"text": "john.doe@gmail.com, john.doe@outlook.com"}
{"text": "john.doe[at]gmail.com"}
{"text": "john.doe gmail.com"}
```

I want this search:

```
GET test/item/_search
{
    "query": 
    {
        "query_string": 
        {
            "query": "*@gmail.com",
            "analyze_wildcard": "true",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": "true",
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

to return only the **first** and **third** documents.

I tried 3 kinds of mapping:
First i tried -

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "email_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "email_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "email_tokenizer": {
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "email_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

than i tried -

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i also tried this one -

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

None of the above worked, actually they all returned all the documents.
Is there an analyzer/tokenizer/parameter that will make Elasticsearch to acknowledge the '@' sign like it does with any other character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with your last setting, by putting the text to not analyze:

```
GET test/item/_search
{
    "query": 
    {
        "wildcard": 
        {
            "text": "*@gmail.com*"
        }
    }
}
```

When using not analyzed field, you should use Term level query but not Full-Text level query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/term-level-queries.html